Connexion routes not populating url_map when using Flask-SocketIO
I’m working on a minimal working example with Connexion and Flask-SocketIO. My openapi.yaml defines two routes, but the url_map only shows one static route when I run the app.
What I’m trying to achieve:

I'm creating a Flask app that uses Connexion to handle the API routes and Flask-SocketIO for WebSocket connections.
When I run the app without Flask-SocketIO, I can access http://localhost:8000/hello via curl or a browser, and I receive the expected response: {"message":"Hello, World!"}. However, despite the functionality, the url_map is still empty. This behavior can be replicated in minApp.py.
When I add Flask-SocketIO back into the app, the routes stop working, and I receive 404 errors.

Error Messages:
Here are the errors I encounter when running the app with Flask-SocketIO:
raise starlette.exceptions.HTTPException(exc.code, detail=exc.description)
starlette.exceptions.HTTPException: 404: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

raise NotFound() from None
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

What I’ve tried:

Running the app without Flask-SocketIO works fine for returning the API responses, but the url_map still appears empty.
When I integrate Flask-SocketIO, I get 404 errors for the defined API routes.
The routes are defined in openapi.yaml. I've tried defining routes explicitly using operatorid: connexionApp.hello, and routing automatically with both RestyResolver and RelativeResolver.

Steps to Reproduce:
The issue can be reproduced using the following example on GitHub:
https://github.com/graham63/connexionApp.git
There is an example with socketio and CORS, and a minimal example with just connexion. There is also a requirements.txt with versions.
What I need help with:

Why isn’t Connexion populating the url_map with my API routes?
How can I resolve the 404 errors that appear when integrating Flask-SocketIO with Connexion?
Any advice on how to correctly set up Connexion and Flask-SocketIO to work together would be appreciated.


I've just reproduced the steps and I can confirm that everything works as expected.
Did you try visiting these urls?
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ui/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/site/layout
The 404 Error codes you receive are because you haven't defined a default path. To add a default path to your application do the following:

Add this to your openapi.yaml paths

  /:
    get:
      summary: Default path
      operationId: default_hello
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Default greeting
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  message:
                    type: string
      description: |
        Returns a basic message to confirm that the API is working.


Add this to your minApp.py API functions

    def default_hello():
    return jsonify({"message": "test"})

Now everything should work without any error codes.

Adding a default path does not change the app's behavior. As mentioned in my original question, routing works as expected when the app is run without Flask-SocketIO using the Uvicorn server provided by Connexion. However, the url_map remains empty, which indicates that the solution you've provided does not address the core issue in connexionApp.py. The primary concern here is integrating Flask-SocketIO while maintaining proper route registration, which is the focus of this question.

For example, if you add @app.route("/hello") above def hello(), the route will appear in the url_map and will work as expected when accessed via http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello. However, Connexion is designed to automatically generate routes from the OpenAPI specification so manually adding route decorators defeats the purpose of using Connexion.
